# Wave curve in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi friends can anyone please help me in this. i want to create a login page in this way

[image]

But it is not working in emulator and android 8 phone. it is working in android 5 phone.
Working fine if i remove the image view which contains curve.
getting this error when i try in android 8 or emulator.

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loginapi/com.example.loginapi.views.Loginactivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in
> com.example.loginapi:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in
> com.example.loginapi:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class
> ImageView
>     at 
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.loginapi:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.loginapi:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class ImageView
>  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.loginapi:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class ImageView
>  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.loginapi:drawable/wave with resource ID
>  #0x7f07007b
>
>  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/wave.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07007b
>     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:876)
>     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:906)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:845)
>     at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:687)
>     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
>     at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
>     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
>     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1061)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
>     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>
> com.example.loginapi.views.Loginactivity.onCreate(Loginactivity.java:59)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
>     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path string cannot be empty.
>     at android.util.PathParser.nCreatePathDataFromString(Native Method)
>     at android.util.PathParser.access$200(PathParser.java:25)
>     at android.util.PathParser$PathData.<init>(PathParser.java:78)
>     at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:2039)
>     at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1990)
>     at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateChildElements(VectorDrawable.java:836)
>     at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:734)
>     at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:144)
>     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1402)
>     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1361)
>     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:939)
>     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:862)
>       ... 41 more
> ```

My code 
wave.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="600dp"
    android:height="600dp"
    android:viewportWidth="600"
    android:viewportHeight="600">

   <path
        android:fillColor="#11b6ed"
        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="#11b6ed"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#11b6ed"
        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="#11b6ed"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#11b6ed"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M0 00L637.5 00L637.5 519.0C528.33 483.94 424.58 482.69 326.25 516.02C227.91 549.35 119.17 545.6 0 504.77L0 00Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#11b6ed"
        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="#11b6ed"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M0 00L637.5 00L637.5 519.0C528.33 483.94 424.58 482.69 326.25 516.02C227.91 549.35 119.17 545.6 0 504.77L0 00Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#11b6ed"
        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="#11b6ed"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M0 00L637.5 00L637.5 519.0C528.33 483.94 424.58 482.69 326.25 516.02C227.91 549.35 119.17 545.6 0 504.77L0 00Z" />
</vector
```

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.Loginactivity"

   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="364dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wave" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/google"
        android:text="Sign In With \n Google"

        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.241"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.535" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebook"
        android:text="Sign In With \n Facebook"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.821"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.535" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.286"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.748" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:hint="@string/tvpassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.286"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.847" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.954" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OR"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.631" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View03"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#acafb0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.921"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.629" />

    <View

        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#acafb0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.148"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.626" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign in to Explico"
        android:textColor="#ed0741"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.53"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.457" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is problem in your image in first 2 path tags `android:pathData=""` is empty.
Because of empty pathData app is crashed and you getting error.

Please use another image or below vector code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="600dp"
    android:height="600dp"
    android:viewportWidth="600"
    android:viewportHeight="600">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#11b6ed"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M0 00L637.5 00L637.5 519.0C528.33 483.94 424.58 482.69 326.25 516.02C227.91 549.35 119.17 545.6 0 504.77L0 00Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#11b6ed"
        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="#11b6ed"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M0 00L637.5 00L637.5 519.0C528.33 483.94 424.58 482.69 326.25 516.02C227.91 549.35 119.17 545.6 0 504.77L0 00Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#11b6ed"
        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="#11b6ed"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M0 00L637.5 00L637.5 519.0C528.33 483.94 424.58 482.69 326.25 516.02C227.91 549.35 119.17 545.6 0 504.77L0 00Z" />
</vector>
```

And use `android:src="@drawable/wave"` instead of  `app:srcCompat="@drawable/wave"`

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If  `srcCompat` you should  use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView`.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="364dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/wave" />
```

And add this in `build.gradle`

```
 android {
   defaultConfig {
      vectorDrawables {
         useSupportLibrary = true
      }
    }
   }
```

**OR**  use `src` instead of `srcCompat` in `ImageView` .

I hope this will help .

Comment: adder Usesupportlibrary already. didn't work, also tried with android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView  Didn't work.